# Sort alphabetically then by case

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How would I sort an array of strings alphabetically and then by case.

Example Input:

```
    ["A","d","B","a","D","c","C","b"]
```

Desired Output:

```
    ["A","a","B","b","C","c","D","d"]
```

Comment: you would use Array#sort with a callback function that compares case insensitively first, and then case sensitively if the first compare is considered equal

Comment: Have a look at [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare first only lower case letters and then move upper case values ahead.

```js
var array = ["A", "d", "B", "a", "D", "c", "C", "b"];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.toLowerCase(),
        bb = b.toLowerCase();

    return aa.localeCompare(bb) || (a === aa) - (b === bb) ;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you would use Array#sort with a callback function that compares case insensitively first, and then case sensitively if the first compare is considered equal

```
["A","d","B","a","D","c","C","b"].sort(function (A, B) {
    var a = A.toLowerCase(), b = B.toLowerCase();
    if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if (A < B) {
        return -1;
    } else if (A > B) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that's possibly less efficient than Jaromanda's version but less code:

`["A","d","B","a","D","c","C","b"].sort((a, b) => String.localeCompare(...(a.toLowerCase() == b.toLowerCase() ? [b, a] : [a.toLowerCase(), b.toLowerCase()])))`.